# Fetching Case history into agent console in service cloud live agent

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, servicecloud

I am learning service cloud live agent. When a customer chats with an agent, if the customer's case is already added, then the agent is able to view the case history in service cloud console. How is that possible? Is it using some information (like email) filled in pre-chat form?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. Every contact has an email address (required field). The contact's related cases are loaded into the console page layout via a query.